# Action mode над Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

Проблемка, `ActionMode`вылазит над тулбаром, а не overlay.
Добавление в стили `android:windowActionModeOverlay` не помогает.
Toolbar в разметке находится в такое иерархии

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

В общем, кто что подскажет? Уже голову сломал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

на

```
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
```

Comment: И в правду помогло) Спасибо огромное!